# Weakest possible assumptions to guarantee consistency in linear regression estimators?

Tags: regression, self-study, estimators, consistency

For a linear regression model where $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$ and $E[\epsilon|X=x]=0$, $Var[\epsilon|X=x]=\sigma^2$ for any $x$. For a sample $(X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)$, I'm wondering if the typical assumption of independence between pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$ and $(X_j,Y_j)$ (where $i\neq j$)  can be weakened to simply uncorrelated (I don't think this can be weakened further). If that's the case, are the following estimators still consistent as $n\to\infty$?

$\hat\beta_1 = \frac{c_{XY}}{s_X^2} \to\beta_1=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}$ or $c_{XY} \to Cov(X,Y)$ and $s_X^2\to Var(X)$

$\hat\beta_0 = \bar Y-\hat\beta_1\bar X \to \beta_0=E[Y]-\beta_1E[X]$

$\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1 X_i)^2 \to \sigma^2=E[(Y-\beta_0-\beta_1 X)^2]$

Comment: Lack of serial correlation is clearly not needed for weak consistency. Standard conditions for weak consistency are mixing-type of assumptions, e.g. strong-mixing or uniform mixing. For strong consistency, martingale assumptions would suffice.